# Losing Window focus in own Visual Studio extension (using EnvDTE)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, envdte

I'm writing a C# document outline extension for Visual Studio 2013.

The idea is to have a outline window and if the user clicks on a outline element the cursor jumps to the linked position in the code document. I'm using the EnvDTE.Document class to realise this:

```
DTE2 dte = GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
var currentDocument = dte.ActiveDocument;

currentDocument.Activate();

var selection = (EnvDTE.TextSelection) CurrentDocument.Selection;
selection.MoveToLineAndOffset(line, offset);
```

I do the activation and selection change in a `OnMouseDoubleClick` event handler.

The issue is that at first the focus changes as intended but than my tool window gets the focus back.
How do I prevent the focus from returning to the my tool window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

**Actual Problem:**

The Issue was caused by the `TreeView` bubble behaviour. I.e. even if you handle the `MouseDoubleClick` event it bubbles up till the tree root element. My first level of `TreeViewItem`s doesn't had my `OnMousDoubleClick` event handler connected. Therefore they reclaimed the focus once the event bubble reached them.

**Solution:**

Connect the `OnMousDoubleClick` handler to **all** `TreeViewItem` element in your tree and let all them call

```
currentDocument.Activate();
```

right at the beginning in the event handler - always.